# QEMU - Can't Connect Between Guest and Host, but Both Connect to Router

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, debian, qemu, bridge

QEMU - Can't Connect Between Guest and Host, but Both Connect to Router.

[Home Router]
|
|-[Host - 192.168.1.80] Ubuntu Desktop
|   |
|   -[Guest - 192.168.1.85] Debian
|-[Other Machine - 192.168.1.50]

Guest is set up to use a bridged interface. I set it up using VirtManager.

The Guest can access the internet without issue.
ping google.com works.

The Other Machine can communicate with Guest and Host okay.
ping 192.168.1.80 works
ping 192.168.1.85 works

Guest and Host do not talk though.
PING 192.168.1.85 (192.168.1.85) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.180 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

What can I change to get the Guest and Host talking to each other?

Answer (score 2):

After doing more research I found that this is the intended behavior of the bridge mode I selected.

[Guest can reach outside network, but can't reach host (macvtap)](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Guest_can_reach_outside_network,_but_can%27t_reach_host_%28macvtap%29)